# System screen started from intent does not survive orientation change

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app I want to want to save contacts in the addressbook via Intent. The Intent works just fine. However, the following screen (Choose in which address book the contact should be saved) does not survive an orientation change of the activity and the devices goes back into my app.
Effectively, my user has to press my button "Save contact" again, and the system screen is shown again.
What I want to achieve is that this system screen will not be killed by an orientation change.

In case my English has failed me, here have a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Add this in your activity tag in manifest

    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: @Zoin-Coder The screen shown is a system dialog, it is not part of the OP's application, so your comment is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can avoid the screen being killed, as the system needs to recreate it to fit the changed screen dimensions.
But you could implement that after killing the screen while orientation change you instantly open the dialog again(maybe even pre filled with the data it contained before).

#### How to build that workarround

You could hold some Boolean variable like 'isDialogActive' in your activity which you set true when the dialog is opened and set to false when the dialog gets closed.

Next up you can save that Boolean to the Bundle in onSaveInstanceState lifecycle function.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
   bundle.putBoolean("is_dialog_active", this.isDialogActive);
}
```

So now when your orientation changes, you safe information whether the dialog was active before the rotation or not to a Bundle. This Bundle survives the orientation change and gets passed to onCreate after the change.So now we can use this information(the Bundle) when the activity is recreated in the onCreate lifecycle function.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    boolean dialogWasActiveBeforeChange = 
             bundle.getBoolean("is_dialog_active")

    if ( dialogWasActiveBeforeChange){
       //use your logic that opens the dialog ( that logic should also set 
       // this.isDialogActive to true )
    }
}
```